# Reverse SSH Tunneling via middleman

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have two machines, both in a VPN network, let's call them A and B and there is a user `John` on his own machine C. A is not discoverable by John but B is. Let's make a user on machine A, 'rose'. What I want is that whenever John does `ssh rose@B -p Y` he should connect to the port X on A. Note that there is no user `rose` on B. Note that an SSH daemon is running on both A and B.
Daemon configuration options are preferred instead of manually establishing tunnels. But manual establishment works for me too. Thanks

I'm sure this has been answered multiple times over years but I am unable to pin a question with the exact situation I'm in.

Comment: I would suggest [starting with this](https://superuser.com/questions/96489/an-ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops).  If that doesn't help, explain why and we can hammer out what is missing.

Comment: You want SSH connections to port `Y` on machine `B` to be forwarded straight to port `X` on machine A?  Sounds like you are looking for "port forwarding" and the tool you would use is `iptables`. There's a serverfault.com Q/A about it here  https://serverfault.com/a/140626/94158

Comment: I was trying to avoid using something like the stream block in nginx or forwarding ports via iptables for this and just use the SSH daemon; but I guess I'll just forward the ports for now.